# ¿Cómo evitar que la última fila de la tabla se divida en dos páginas?

Tags: c#, itextsharp, itext

Tengo una tabla en itext7 en c#, la ultima fila se divide en 2 dos paginas, como hago para evitar eso? y que la fila pase a la siguiente pagina, cabe resaltar que estoy utilizando un ciclo para traer los datos a la tabla.

```cs
            Table tablaProductos = new Table(9).UseAllAvailableWidth();

            string[] columnasProductos = { "NRO", "ITEM", "DESCRIPCIÓN", "U.M.", "CANT.", "VALOR UNITARIO ", "VALOR BRUTO", "IVA", "VALOR NETO" };

            tablaProductos.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

            foreach (string columna in columnasProductos)
            {
                tablaProductos.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(columna)).SetFont(bold).SetFontSize(8f).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            }

            foreach (Producto aproducto in productos)
            {

                tablaProductos.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(aproducto.ID.ToString()).AddStyle(styleCell2)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));

                tablaProductos.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(aproducto.ItemCode).AddStyle(styleCell2)));
                tablaProductos.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(aproducto.ItemDescription).AddStyle(styleCell2)));
                            
                tablaProductos.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(nombreUnidades).AddStyle(styleCell2)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
                tablaProductos.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(aproducto.Quantity.ToString()).AddStyle(styleCell2)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));

                tablaProductos.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph((string.Format("{0:C}", aproducto.PriceAmount)).Replace(" ", "")).AddStyle(styleCell2)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));

                tablaProductos.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph((string.Format("{0:C0}", aproducto.LineExtensionAmount)).Replace(" ", "")).AddStyle(styleCell2)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));

                

            
            documento.Add(tablaProductos);
```

[image: quiero evitar justamente lo de la fila 33 y que esta fila se ajuste a la otra pagina automaticamente]

quiero evitar que pase lo de la imagen y la fila 33 pase a la siguiente hoja

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.